# I'm born or I was born, which one to use

Tags: word-choice, tense

Should I say *I'm born in* or *I was born in*?

Can I say *I'm born in Paris in 1900*, or should I say *I was born in Paris in 1990*?

Comment: "I am born" is the first line of Charles Dickens' novel _David Copperfield_. When he wrote that line, however, he was using the narrative present: First line of book = first day of life for David Copperfield = the character DC is born. Otherwise, it's idiomatic to say "I **was** born..." You can say "I'm from Paris" if you were born there but don't live there now, but it's strange to say "I'm born in Paris in 1990" (1900 is virtually impossible for all intents and purposes today).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"I was born in Paris in 1990" is the correct statement to use.

*"I'm"* is a condensed form of *"I am"* which is *present tense*, as you are talking about a past event *"I was"* is used.

Comment: Present tense would never be used to talk about  someone's birth? I always did til today

Comment: @JonathandeM.- [Sometimes it is](http://www.hymnsandcarolsofchristmas.com/Hymns_and_Carols/he_is_born_the_divine_christ_chi1.htm) but it's when the birth is happening now, not in the past.

Comment: @JonathandeM: In particular "I am born" will pretty much always be wrong (except perhaps in a 3rd person autobiographical narrative), but certainly in normal life, "I am born" is always wrong.

Comment: @Matt "I am born" could also be used in a metaphorical sense--"I am born again" after a spiritual awakening or some such event.  But yes, as people cannot talk at the moment of their birth, it's unlikely to say "I am born" in the literal sense ;) +1 to your comment!

Comment: I am always struggling with this, since (in my home languages, Afrikaans) we sometimes use the present tense for life changing events. E.g. (directly translated from afrikaans): I am in born in 1990. I am married in 2013.

Comment: That's not an explanation at all. As Romance language use the present of "to be" with the past participle. So, it's not an explanation why English uses this structure. It seems an English specificity, rather than a logical rule.

Answer (score 0):

"I **was** born" - since this is a passive form. The mother bears the child, and when she brings him/her (*it*, in British English, by the way) forth, the child is said to **be born**.

The active verb "nascere/nascer/naître" is replaced by this passive, semantically equivalent to "my mother has born me", in English, German - ich bin geboren (worden) - and other languages.

Comment: _my mother has birthed me_, perhaps?

Comment: It's a passive form, but used with the "to be" in the present in many, many, many languages.