# "I'm born and brought up in India" - I don't want to use the 'past' tense here

Tags: past-tense

I read this [question here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/im-born-or-i-was-born-which-one-to-use) and this one is different because the *second clause* is in present tense.

> I'm born and brought up in India. - *too commonly practiced in India*.

*I was born in India* is correct over *I'm born in India*. I am pretty clear on that, but then if I want to include *brought up* which is still effective (present), how do I say that?

> I was born and brought up in India. - does not relate the sentence to the present time then. As both are in past
>
> *I was born in India* + *I was brought up in India.* - **no**. I AM brought up in India, I'm *still* here.

Comment: As the answers show correctly, being brought up normally refers to your childhood. So unless you really want to make a point of not being mature yet, ans still being in your childhood, there is no good reason to refuse the use of the past tense. In case of a grown up I would _expect_ their upbringing to have finished when they utter this kind of sentence :)

Comment: Just say "I'm from India". It's implied that you were born and raised while still being present tense.

Comment: "I'm born" is also present tense, I think.  You wouldn't normally say that.  It might work in an autobiography written in that style, e.g. (first line) "Let us review my life to date.  To begin - I am born [...]"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The expression you want is

> I was born and raised in India.

Both verbs are completed actions, so they are expressed in the past tense.  "Raised" means that you spent your childhood there, and is neutral on the issue of whether you are currently living in India or not.  You could also say "brought up" instead, but "born and raised" is a more convenient expression.

---

Incidentally, a related expression is

> I'm Indian, born and bred.

That has a slightly different meaning. *To be bred* means to be brought up in a specific way, so this sentence means that you have very strong characteristically Indian habits due to being brought up there.  This sentence is also neutral on the issue of where you currently reside.

Comment: FWIW doesn't "born and bred" *literally* mean as if for livestock: not merely born in a place but bred of stock from there and hence presumed characteristic? Idiomatically though it means what 200_success says, typical of the place due to birth and upbringing. I certainly wouldn't tell a second-generation immigrant that they "technically" weren't bred in the place they were born, if they used the phrase ;-)

Comment: "Born and bred" has racial overtones. It suggests "I was born in India and so were my parents and their parents and..." as distinct from "You were born in India but your parents were immigrants." Breeding refers to your ancestry, not the way you were brought up.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Several dictionaries agree: [breeding](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/breeding) could refer to either ancestry or upbringing. I had never considered the racial overtones before, but now that you mention it, I can see how it could be construed that way.

Comment: @200_success In the US (and perhaps Canada and parts of Europe), it's not as big a deal given the racial melting pot we have.  In almost anywhere else it may be more of an issue (as in a topic for discussion/debate rather than a problem).

Comment: Yeah, I think **bred** and **breeding** originally referred to parentage/ancestry but, they gradually came to refer to how your are raised in some circumstances too.

Comment: I was always taught that "raised is for livestock, reared is for children."

Comment: +1 These are both good suggestions.  Another option: _I am a lifelong resident of India._

Answer (score 22):

The answer is contextual. *Brought up* means *cared for, raised or reared, as a child*. It does not mean *where one lives*. Are you still the subject of the process of child rearing?

If yes (you are still being raised):

> I was born and am being brought up in India.

If no (you are a fully fledged adult):

> I was born and brought up in India.

If you want to describe both your birthplace and current residence:

> I was born and currently live in India.

Here, *currently* is optional and may be ellipted.

Dictionary entries for *brought up*:

- [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bring-sb-up)
- [Oxford (scroll down a fair amount)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bring)

Comment: What a 30-yr-old will say? *I **am** brought up in this place* or *I **was** brought up in this place.*

Comment: *Was brought up*, because at age 30 the speaker is (presumably) no longer being taken care of (provided with food, shelter, instruction, etc.) by their parents, meaning the action has completed. *Being brought up* is a continuous process, so one is either actively being reared or has finished being brought up.

Comment: An alternative phrase that's very common is "I was born and raised in [insert location]".  In general conversation (in the US at least) this would be the more common wording; "I was born and brought up in [insert location]" sounds a tad awkward/overly formal.

Answer (score 3):

> I was *brought up* in India

refers to where you were when you were growing up. Its similar to:

> I was *raised* in India
>   I *grew up* in India

I don't think you would hear children use such phrases. To my knowledge it would only be used by adults. At that point, it is in the past, so its in the past tense.

Answer (score -2):

*He was born in India* - the event of his birth happened in India, some years ago. 
*He is born in India* - he is today a person who was born in India. Yesterday, he was also a person who was born in India, and he tomorrow he will also be a person born in India. But we are talking about today, so he *is* born in India. You might say "He is India born". You often hear "he is Oxford educated". "He is India born" would mean that this isn't just the place where he happened to be born, but that it is of importance to describe him today.

You use the past tense if you are talking about events that happened in the past. You can use the present tense if you are talking about the past events making him the person that he is today. "I am born in India" does that. "I am born at the hospital near my parents' home" - that would be wrong, because that event doesn't describe the person you are today. Or "I am born in India, but my parents moved to China two weeks after my birth" - I'd assume that two weeks in India didn't have much influence on the person, so I'd use "I was born... " in that case.

You may also search for the lyrics of "Born in the USA" by Bruce Springsteen. Apart from finding some "interesting" words, you'll also see the line "*I'm born in the US of A*".

Comment: No, your answer is factually incorrect.  "He is **Indian** born" is grammatical, but archaic and highly unusual.  "He is India born" is not even vaguely grammatical, and it's not idiomatic either.  Nowhere in Springsteen's "Born in the USA" is the line "I'm born in the US of A".

Comment: This is wrong.  The line in the Springsteen song is "I was born in the U.S.A."  Being born is exiting the birth canal, and it's over when the newborn is out of its mother.  It has nothing to do with the influence a country has on you over time after you were born.